# Between taking longer time. Tuning SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have the below query which is taking long execution time aprox 20 mins for a set of row 1345222. I there a way to tune this, specially the Between clause comparison?

```
<code>
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(32) */ upexp.item,
                  upexp.loc,
                  startdate,
                  sku_exp.bucket_size,
                  MAX(upexp.sku_multiplier) OVER (PARTITION BY upexp.item,upexp.loc) max_sm
                        FROM
                                (SELECT bucket bkt,
                                        MIN(dates) OVER (PARTITION BY bucket) minbk,
                                        MAX(dates)  OVER (PARTITION BY bucket) maxbk
                                FROM (
                                        SELECT LEVEL AS sl,
                                        NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * LEVEL - 8,'SATURDAY') AS dates,
                                        CEIL (LEVEL/4) AS bucket
                                        FROM DUAL
                                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ((4 - MOD (78, 4) + 78) + 78)) yy
                               -- GROUP BY bucket
                                ) minmaxdate ,
                        stsc.u_promo_sku_expand sku_exp,
                        stsc.u_promo_upload_expand upexp
                        WHERE sku_exp.bucket_size = 4
                        AND sku_exp.startdate BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk
                        AND upexp.item = sku_exp.item
                        AND upexp.loc = sku_exp.loc
                        AND upexp.u_country = sku_exp.u_country
                        AND ((eff BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk+6)
                        OR ( disc BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk+6)
                        OR ( eff <= minmaxdate.minbk AND disc >= minmaxdate.maxbk+6))

</code>
```

Comment: Where is the plan? '(eff BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk+6) or  eff <= minmaxdate.minbk AND disc >= minmaxdate.maxbk+6)' in last predicate section is true in any case

Comment: Do you have any index defined for the actual tables? Also, I don't quite understand why you have the `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` inside the whole query. Can't you move it out?

Comment: try with group by  both , instead of MIN/MAX OVER. And move out the connect by query into a WITH

Comment: that high DOP is used at all in the plan?

Comment: @FDavidov: yes , I have the index on the actual tables. Cant remove the SELECT FROM DUAL ,because i need to calculate the MIN and Max Dates (only Saturdays )starting beginning of the year to n days with the bucket = 4. That is the first 4 saturdays is 1 group, then the next four saturdays is another group etc...

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see in which way this particular select depends on the contents of any table. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @HarshilShah pls add the execution plan to the description

Comment: @FDavidov it seems to OK, he needs some properties of items in the specific location in the specific date range

Comment: @Thomas I understand that, but if this particular part is independent of the contents of any table (as it appears to be), he could simply calculate the values outside the BIG select and use them literally as a list. Again, I might be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

This block

```
(SELECT bucket bkt,
   MIN(dates) OVER (PARTITION BY bucket) minbk,
   MAX(dates)  OVER (PARTITION BY bucket) maxbk
FROM (
     SELECT LEVEL AS sl,
         NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * LEVEL - 8,'SATURDAY') AS dates,
         CEIL (LEVEL/4) AS bucket
     FROM DUAL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ((4 - MOD (78, 4) + 78) + 78)) yy
     -- GROUP BY bucket
     )
```

seems to be useless since you need only min and max value.

Try this one:

```
WITH minmaxdate AS
   (SELECT 
       NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * 1 - 8,'SATURDAY') AS minbk,
       NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * ((4 - MOD (78, 4) + 78) + 78) - 8,'SATURDAY') AS maxbk
    FROM dual)
SELECT item, loc, startdate, sku_exp.bucket_size,
    MAX(upexp.sku_multiplier) OVER (PARTITION BY item, loc) max_sm
FROM stsc.u_promo_sku_expand sku_exp
    JOIN stsc.u_promo_upload_expand upexp USING (item, loc, u_country)
    CROSS JOIN minmaxdate
WHERE sku_exp.bucket_size = 4
    AND sku_exp.startdate BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk
    AND (
        eff BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk+6 
        OR (eff <= minmaxdate.minbk AND disc >= minmaxdate.maxbk+6)
        OR disc BETWEEN minmaxdate.minbk AND minmaxdate.maxbk+6
    );
```

Comment: I get this :ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier. BUT THIS WORKS FINE. SELECT item, loc, startdate, bucket_size --MAX(sku_multiplier) OVER (PARTITION BY sku_exp.item,sku_exp.loc) max_sm FROM stsc.u_promo_sku_expand sku_exp JOIN stsc.u_promo_upload_expand upexp USING (item, loc, u_country) WHERE sku_exp.bucket_size = 4